# Pulling words that begin with a specific sequence in each row

Tags: python, pandas, keyword

I have a data-set with 2 key columns. Column 1 contains a special identifier that is unique to each row. Column two is tons of text. Within column 2, there will be 2 shipping codes each beginning with "1Z". 
I need to pull these codes, save them as a separate row and associate them back to the unique identifier. 
End goal is, if I have a 2x10 table, the output will be a 2x20 table (assuming each row contains 2 shipping codes.

I have tried contains using pandas and even tried regex doing a loop for each row.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then, edit the question with a sample of your data and the expected output. Also, please share what you have tried so far ? StackOverflow isn't a *Write for me Code Editor*.

Comment: will do. I will add more detail and repost.

Comment: Also, try to give more information about these shipping codes and how you recognize them (we only know it starts with 1Z, which is already good, but with more details, it can help to be more accurate when extracting them). Do they have a fixed length? Only alphanumeric characters? Is there any specific word that appears systematically before/after?